# translation of "private tutor"

Tags: traducción

Having trouble coming up with a clear way of expressing "private tutor" (American English) in a letter to a school district in Spanish.  Suggestions?  (I don't want there to be any confusion as to whether I'm talking about a tutor or a legal guardian.)

¿Cómo puedo expresar el concepto de *private tutor* o *private tutoring* en español, en una carta dirigida a la escuela?  La idea: es una persona que da clases particulares para regularización.

---

Profesor particular -- sounds promising.  I'm not sure how to get from here to "tutoring."

Comment: I think perhaps that "clases particulares" o "lecciones particulares" might work for tutoring, but I'm not a native speaker, so I'm not sure in the least.

Answer (score 7):

In Chile we say **profesor particular**.

Comment: Es igual en España: un profesor particular.

Comment: En argentina también

Answer (score 6):

The literal translation is "tutor privado", but you can use "tutor particular", "profesor particular", or "maestro particular", if you want to refer to a legal guardian most common use is "tutor legal".

Answer (score 3):

In Spain I would say "profesor particular"

Answer (score 2):

`Tutor(a) particular` is an option but it is not the most used way, I'll prefer `profesor (a) / maestro (maestra) particular` but you need to check for a specific region/ country.